# replacing innerHTML stops other scripts working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following function to exchange phone numbers in an HTML. I want to make it completely independent of using class names to select elements. Basically it should work without touching the HTML code.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( /54321/g, '12345' );
```

But using it renders many other scripts on the page non functional (drop down menus, buttons, etc.)

What is wrong with this replacement function? Why does it touch the function of other scripts?

What would be a better solution?

I need to change something like this

```
<a href="tel:+54321"><span>+54321</span></a>
```

into this

```
<a href="tel:+12345"><span>+12345</span></a>
```

Note that I have to change a text and a href="" element.

Comment: better solution is to find parent tag of value (in this case 54321) and then replace

Comment: instead of replacing elements in the full page ( it should waste alot of time aswell) you can set id´s to those phone numbers and replace by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace a string in text and `href` attributes *only* (avoiding other attributes, tags, etc.) you'll need to attack both problems separately.  Find all of the `href` attributes, find all of the text nodes, and replace in both.  Something like:

```js
var from = "54321", to = "12345";

var textNodes = [];

function findText(pnode) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pnode.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    var node = pnode.childNodes[i];
    
    if (node.nodeType == 3) { // text
      textNodes.push(node);
    } 
    else {
      findText(node);
    }
  }
}

var refs = document.querySelectorAll('[href*="' + from + '"]');

findText(document.body);

for (var i = 0; i < refs.length; ++i) {
  refs[i].href = refs[i].href.replace(from, to);
}

for (i = 0; i < textNodes.length; ++i) {
  textNodes[i].textContent = textNodes[i].textContent.replace(from, to);
}
```

```css
/* make sure we're not replacing where we shouldn't */

#p54321 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="number_link" href="tel:+54321"><span>+54321</span></a>

<a class="otherclass" href="tel:+54321 x5"><span>+54321 x5</span></a>

<p id="p54321">This should remain red if its <code>id</code> is unchanged.</p>
```

If you're *only* changing `class=number_link` `href`s, and the `<span>` therein, we can save some code:

```js
var from = "54321",
  to = "12345";

$('.number_link').attr('href', function() {
  return this.href.replace(from, to);
});

$('.number_link span').html(function() {
  return this.innerHTML.replace(from, to);
})
```

```css
#div54321 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>number_link: <a class="number_link" href="tel:+54321"><span>+54321</span></a></p>

<p>not number_link: <a class="otherclass" href="tel:+54321 x5"><span>+54321 x5</span></a></p>

<p id="div54321">Don't change this id - this should still be red!</p>
```

Answer (score 8):

When you overwrite the HTML content, then the DOM for that portion of the page is rebuilt (in this case, your entire `<body>`). Any event handlers bound to elements on the page will be lost, since they would have been associated with the DOM elements that were removed in the process.

Comment: Is there a way around it?

Comment: @alev well you could traverse the DOM looking only for text nodes, and perform the replacement on each text node you find. That way, the HTML element nodes will remain unchanged. But that only would work if the replacements are in fact for text nodes. If you're performing the replacement on HTML attribute values, then you'd have to look explicitly for those while traversing the DOM.

Comment: @alev the best thing to do would be to produce the page content with the proper content in the first place :)

Comment: Adjust the parts that need adjustment, don't overwrite the entire page.

Comment: @Pointy  
This code is an attempt to improve an AdWords phone tracking script. It changes a phone number only if someone clicks on an ad and then visits a landing page. So, the page content is proper, but needs some dynamic adjustments based on source of visitor.

Comment: @alev well maybe the replacement can be performed in the code that handles the clicks?

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understand your Problem, but i don´t know why you would change this in reverse order?

[fiddle](https://jsbin.com/xuyixiqohe/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ChangeTel</title>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
    <body>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      <a class="number_link" href="tel:+54321"><span>+54321</span></a>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      <a class="number_link" href="tel:+98765"><span>+98765</span></a>
    <script>
      [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('number_link'),
      function(el){
        var hrefTel=el.href.split('+')[1];
        var elHref=el.href.split('+')[0];
        el.setAttribute('href',elHref+'+'+hrefTel.match(/./g).reverse().join(''));
       el.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML='+'+hrefTel.match(/./g).reverse().join('');
      });
  </body>  
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But since I want to make the code independent of HTML changes I can't use the class names for selection.

Comment: Then you have to specify that also in your question and not simply change the question.

Yesterday stood `class = number_link` in your question.

For such a nonsense I have absolutely no understanding....

Comment: You are right. I didn't think this would lead to a misunderstanding when I wrote the initial question. Sometimes it takes a few iterations to get the question right if you want to get the answer you desire. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: alter selector to `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="tel"]')`

Comment: While I was looking into this function `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="tel"]'`I came across the following information that might be of interest to you: https://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/

Comment: I will have to use another solution though that treats hrefs and text nodes separately, as the website sources will not always use both. Plus not all text nodes will be enclosed in spans. But you gave me all the tools to build the code myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
<div id="replaceContent"> <a class="number_link" href="tel:+54321"><span>+54321</span></a></div>
```

Later you can replace the html content of this particular div alone instead of replacing the entire page.

```
$("#replaceContent").html(<a class="number_link" href="tel:+12345"><span>+12345</span></a>)
```

If you have attached any event listener with the anchor tag ,those won't work now. Because the HTML content inside replaceContent div is rendered newly now.

To overcome this you can use ,

```
$("a").on("click",function() { });
```

jQuery on() used to bind the events to the dynamically added DOM elements .

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But since I want to make the script independent of the HTML code and interchangeable between websites I can't use class names to select the elements.